# Node module not showing in list of globally installed modules

Tags: node.js, npm

I did `npm install -g <module_name>` to globally install a node module. The module got installed and i see it located in `/usr/lib/node_modules`.
But when i run `npm -g ls` i dont see the module listed. What could be the reason for that ?

Thanks

Comment: does it show if you run "npm ls"?

Comment: the very same problem here!